# Express.get is getting variable name instead of it's value from AngularJS ui-router

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

As I mention in my title, when I send a param to the url using ui-router, and try to use express.get(url), I get the :param name instead of it's value.

Here is my code:

AngularJS ui-router state:

```
.state('post', {
    url: '/blog/:postID',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/post.html',
    controller: 'PostCtrl'
})
```

AngularJS http request

```
$http.get('/blog/:postID').success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.singlePost = data;
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

HTML ui-router url

```
<h1><a ui-sref="post({ postID: post._id })">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
```

express.get() method

```
app.get('/blog/:id', function(req, res) {
    Post.findById(req.params.id, function(err, singlePost){
        console.log(singlePost);    
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(singlePost);
        }
    });
});
```

I get the following error in the console

```
{ [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":postID" at path "_id"]
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":postID" at path "_id"',
  name: 'CastError',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: ':postID',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined }
```

Any help and/or explanation of why it's happening for a newbie would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You have to make a http request from your angular js application to node server. I do not see that here.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to add it. My bad. Added it

Comment: I am surprised to see your http request targeted at /blog.

Comment: It's targeted at /blog/:postID

Comment: Even then how does your http request processing such parameter. I guess your express cannot parse such request.

Answer (score 0):

I am inferring here that you are trying to make an ajax request from your angular application inside PostCtrl controller.

```
.state('post', {
 url: '/blog/:postID',
 templateUrl: 'app/views/post.html',
 controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
    var postID = $stateParams.postID;
 }
})
```

In your controller you can now make an ajax request with whatever have received.

```
var req = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:3300/blog',
      headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      data: $httpParamSerializer(postID)
    };

$http.post(req).then(function(success){},function(error){});
```

Your complete state would be:

```
.state('post', {
 url: '/blog/:postID',
 templateUrl: 'app/views/post.html',
 controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
    var postID = $stateParams.postID;
    var req = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:3300/blog',
      headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      data: $httpParamSerializer(postID)
    };

  $http.post(req).then(function(success){},function(error){});  
 }
})
```

Of course you need to add your dependencies for `$httpParamSerializer`

Comment: I forgot to add my http request inside my controller, I added it now. I'll check what I did different